# Get name of class during static construction

Tags: java, static

In `C#` I can assign the name of a class to a local static variable like this.

```
 public class MyClass
 {
      private static string TAG = typeof(MyClass).Name;
 }
```

I've found this very useful, because the value of the string automatically updated if the class is refactored to another name. Handy for tagging debug messages and such.

Is something like this possible in `Java`?

```
 public class MyClass
 {
      private static String TAG = ????;
 }
```

I know I could use `getClass().getName()` but that requires a reference to an object. Is there a way to do this on a static variable?

Comment: Removing `[c#]` as the answer won't have anything to do with C#

Comment: @PeterLawrey The answer won't, the question has everything to do with it.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I assume when you are searching for c# you would prefer answers about c#, rather than question which have a passing reference to c#, but not the answers.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You have a point there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to assign the name of a class to field instead of writing.

```
MyClass.TAG
```

you can write

```
MyClass.class.getName();
```

If you really need to you can assign this to TAG but I don't see the point.

Answer (score 2):

A trick is also available that does not require programmer's knowledge of the class name beforehand:

```
public class MyClass
  {
    private static String TAG =
        new Object() { }.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getName();
  }
```

This trick uses a nested anonymous `Object` subclass to get hold of the execution context. It has a benefit of being copy/paste safe in case of cloning your code across different classes...

Comment: That is very clever. Would this allow TAG to hold the name of a derived class if MyClass was abstract?

Comment: Unfortunately no. One will have to replicate this piece of code in every derived class where it may be needed...